# simple d3.js relationship graph from mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3.js to graph relationships from a mysql table. Here is an example table to explain what i'm trying to achieve.

```
+----+---------+-------+------+
| id | name    | entry | type |
+----+---------+-------+------+
|  1 | ObjectA | 100   | ID1  |
|  2 | ObjectA | 101   | ID1  |
|  3 | ObjectB | 101   | ID1  |
|  4 | ObjectB | 102   | ID1  |
|  5 | ObjectC | 102   | ID1  |
|  6 | ObjectC | 100   | ID1  |
|  7 | ObjectA | 200   | ID2  |
|  8 | ObjectA | 201   | ID2  |
|  9 | ObjectB | 201   | ID2  |
| 10 | ObjectB | 202   | ID2  |
| 11 | ObjectC | 202   | ID2  |
| 12 | ObjectC | 200   | ID2  |
+----+---------+-------+------+
```

ObjectA has ID1 with 101 that connects to ObjectB ID1 of 101
ObjectB has ID1 with 102 that connects to ObjectC ID1 of 102
ObjectC has ID1 with 100 that connects to ObjectA ID1 of 100

My end goal is to show ObjectA,ObjectB,ObjectC as three seperate circles that are connected to eachother with both blue and red lines representing the ID1 and ID2 relationships.

So far I'm outputting the table to json as recommended widely in videos and stuff i have read. I'm using php for this.

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "ObjectA",
    "entry": "100",
    "type": "ID1",
},
etc..
```

and then reading that from within a html file

```
d3.json(
  "mysql_table_to_json.php?table=objects",
       function (error, json) {
then something..
})
```

the something part i haven't figured out yet.. and i find it really hard to wrap my head around javascript as I'm used to php and python coding myself. i was really really really hoping somone would take pity on me and whip up a little example i could start hacking around.

so any ideas and examples on how to proceed would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the data you have above to create a visualisation that *seems* to fit your description.  You can find it [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6680294).  It's pretty boring at the minute but I'm sure more data would make it more interesting.  Note that I had to work your data a round a little to get into a format that was going to work with this example, but pythons a pretty good tool for that sort of thing so you should have an issue there.

The other thing that I thought of when I read you're description was Parallel Sets and Kai Chang has created a plugin for that which can be found [here](http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/).

If you haven't already I'd recommend looking at the [d3 examples page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) to get some more ideas about what visualisation would suit your datasets and desired outcomes. And besides there some really cool stuff there.

Comment: That example helped a lot! I'm still having trouble formulating nested loops to work through the data. I'm fighting the urge to mix server-side php code into the mix for the loops since I'd like to do this with javascript in the browser.

Comment: or alternatively i could generate a table in mysql and use php to convert the table i currently have to a source/destination based table and pass that to js .. not really sure what is the best approach for scalability if i wanted say 100 objects with an average of 5 relationships each or something silly like that..

Comment: There are a number of [d3 array](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_entries) helpers to consider as well.